# Could anyone help me with y-axis of the image

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i have a problem with y-axis when i get snapshot from camera,the y-axis start from 450 to 50 ... I want to start from the small number to big number and not vice versa ....could anyone help me to fix this problem.... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can change the axis direction using the axis properties:

```
set(gca,'YDir','reverse') % starts at the top of the figure
set(gca,'YDir','normal') %starts at the bottom of the figure
```

Comment: it is not working the y-axis is still the same ... see this pic
http://s9.postimg.org/i08ink1cf/image.png

Comment: I missed that you were plotting an image. Use 'normal' instead of 'reverse' to have the axis start at the bottom of the figure.

Comment: hi ... there is a big problem ...when i put your code and then get snapshot ,,Picture becomes inverted,,,how i can fix this problem

Comment: I need more information. Are you using snapnow? How are you publishing the output? By inverted do you mean upside down?  You should probably ask a new question.